# Updating UI from the background (QtConcurrent) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

> I am trying to read a log file in the background and update the text in
>   `QTextEdit`. Below is the code. But once I emit the signal the UI freezes. Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong here with QtConcurrent?
>
> **Connect the signal to the slot**

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(SignalUpdateLog(QString)),this,SLOT(SlotUpdateLog(QString)));
```

> **Update Log Button Event**

```
void on_ButtonClicked()
{
   ...
   //Show busy dialog
   QtConcurrent::run(this, &ClassA::UpdateReaderLog);
 }
```

> **Background Task**

```
void ClassA::UpdateReaderLog()
{

    QFile file("/home/Debug.txt");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        in.setCodec("UTF-8");
        while (!file.atEnd())
        {
          emit SignalUpdateLog(in.readLine());
        }

        emit SignalUpdateLog("finishedReadingFile");
        qWarning("\nRead finished");

    }
    else
    {
        //! emit signal to show failure pop up
    }
}
```

> **The Slot**

```
void ClassA::SlotUpdateReaderLog(QString str)
{

    if(str.contains("finishedReadingFile"))
    {
        qWarning("\nSetting reader screen");
        SetToScreen(SCREEN__READER_LOG);

        //Close the busy dialog
    }
    else
    {
        ui->textEditReaderLog->append(str);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Changed to emit signal to show pop up from UpdateReaderLog() for file open failure

Comment: in `ClassA::UpdateReaderLog()` you are showing a pop-up (in case of file reading failure) from a thread other than the main thread, see [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread). can you read the file successfully?

Comment: How big is the file? Does your application freeze indefinitely or just for a few seconds? Try debugging `QThread::currentThread` to make sure everything is run in the correct thread. Also, is `SlotUpdateReaderLog` different than `SlotUpdateLog` or is it just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Please read [Threads and Event loops](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects) first.

```
while (!file.atEnd())
{
  emit SignalUpdateLog(in.readLine());
}
```

You are emitting signals continuously in this `while(!file.atEnd())` loop but event loop has no chance to process these signals and send to the destined object; since UI is not being drawn because of this busy loop your UI is frozen.

Another problem is that your slot is being invoked in wrong thread, you need to `Qt::connect` your signal with `Qt::QueuedConnection` as a third argument. It might fix your problem but be aware of your design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Connect signal-slot with Qt::QueuedConnection.  In multi-thread, you should connect signals-slots with different types depending on practical situations .